# Why would sqlite3 fail to set cache_size?

Tags: ios, sqlite

I'm trying to track down a strange bug reported by one user of an iOS app. The crash happens here:

```
if(sqlite3_exec(database, "pragma cache_size=50;", NULL, NULL, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) 
{
    NSAssert1(0, @"Error: failed to set cache size");
}
```

The assertion trips for just this one user. However, this call has always returned `SQLITE_OK` for years and for countless users, in the wild and in testing, without ever tripping the assert.

I can't reproduce this problem myself, even with the same hardware, iOS version and SQLite database, so I'm a bit stumped.

What could cause `pragma cache_size = X` to fail?

Comment: This would be answered by the error code, or `sqlite3_errmsg()`.

Comment: @CL Agreed - unfortunately, that's not part of the crash report.